# Io redirection vs file logging performance c/c++

Tags: c, c++, high-performance

Is there a performance difference from a latency point of view if we do a regular printf and redirect stdout to a file when running the program ( e.g., ./a.out > log.txt  2>&1 ) vs using fprintf and log to a file.

Specifically I use ACE logging and currently redirect io to a file when I run the program. Is it beneficial to associate logger with file instead from a performance point of view.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?  It *should* be pretty much the same since `printf` just calls `fprintf` on file descriptor 0.

Comment: So, it's easy to say that shell redirection is likely to be slower than ``fprintf()`` inside native code. But by how much? it's probably negligible in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware that the "latency" might include the stdio system buffering enough output for an "efficient" filesystem write.  See `man 3 setbuf` for some further information. The buffering is on a per `FILE *` basis, so `stderr` is typically unbuffered, while `stdout` is typically buffered. That's why output to `stderr` and output to `stdout` end up appearing out-of-order when they are both directed to the same file, as per your example.

If you've got a `FILE *` instance that your program opened, unless you've done `setbuf()` on it, or do regular 'fflush()` calls, the "latency" is not possible to predict.

I've ended up putting lots of `fflush()` calls into programs that crash, so that the output to stdout actually makes it into a log file before a crash. Cheap, but dirty.